# the ability to change color in the N2 cms text editor

Tags: text-editor, html-editor, n2, n2cms

I'm using N2 cms, and it is really piece of work, 
I want to be able to change the text color in the Html Text editor, it has every thing that is needed except this.

is that easy to be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your css file, put a class with color attribute. Then go to the Html Text Editor and refer to this class. This is some code.

In your stylesheet :

```
   .textColor
   {
       color:Red;
   }
```

In the Html Text Editor :

```
 <h1 class="textColor"> the text is in red</h1>
```

**Edit**

**Best Method**

You can enable the forecolor on tinyMCE by putting the following code in Web.config/n2/edit tag

```
 <tinyMCE enabled="true">
        <settings> 
          <add key="theme_advanced_buttons1" value="bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect"/>
          <add key="theme_advanced_buttons2" value="cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor"/>
          <add key="extended_valid_elements" value="hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style],pre[class],code[class],iframe[src|name|class|style|frameborder]"/>
          <add key="theme_advanced_disable" value="help,paste,emotions,iespell,styleprops"/>
          <add key="relative_urls" value="true"/>
          <add key="apply_source_formatting" value="true"/>
        </settings>
      </tinyMCE>
```